# Intent service and its advantage

Tags: android

Can anyone please share what's the real advantage of using `IntentService` instead of `AsycTask` or a thread or even service and thread?

Answer (score 4):

**Intent Service**
No communication with Main thread. Run on worker thread. No parallel task. All requests are handled on a single worker thread.

**Thread**
Run on its own. Multiple Thread for parallel process.

**Service**
Run in main thread without UI. Long running process block main thread. Use thread inside service for long running process.

**AsyncTask**
Long running process commmnicate back to main thread. Run in worker thread.

You must know the exact purpose of each before you decide which one to use in your implementation.

Comment: i  have a usecase in my app where  i want to download different files as per user request but the download should be fast  so i have to go for parallel download.And also if the user  exit the app  the already initiated download have to continue.in this case what would be the better option thread or  multiple  intentservice for each download request(not a good approach i think)

Comment: The Android documentation states the AsyncTasks should not be used for more than a few seconds... I wouldn't call this a "long running process" as you put it.

Answer (score 4):

There are several primary advantages to using IntentService.

- Easy to implement.  It only has one method that you need to override
- Easy to pass data to.  You just use the intent extras mechanism
- Available everywhere in your app.  It's registered in manifest.xml
- Handles multiple intents. These are queued and executed sequentially.
- Self terminating.  When intents in the queue have been processed, the service stops.

Combined, these advantages make the IntentService mechanism both convenient and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

`Service` can run in the background even when the user is not interacting with your application. Use service if this is your scenario. Use `Thread` if you need to perform some work not in your main thread, but only while the user is interracting with your application. Typical example is playing music while your activity is running, than you create thread. `AsyncTask` is just a helper class for thread.

Service is running in main thread of the application, so if you are performing some blocking operations you still have to create a new thread within the service, or you use `IntentService` which already does it for you. `IntentService` is just a service with worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a lot of talk about regular Services and not IntentServices. I'm researching the difference right now and mostly it seems to boil down to whether you want to run a bunch of things in parallel (AsyncTask) or if you want to spawn a worker thread that has a queue. The AsyncTask does seem tied to the Activity and the IntentService seems to run independently of it.

If you ever have done bundles between activities and have dealt with a callback system, then an IntentService turns out to be pretty simple. Feel free to talk about AsyncTask

Most of my designs tends to like the queuing aspect of IntentServices. This is especially nice if you are working with a resource that mostly runs separate from the UI thread, and want to avoid hammering a resource like a single-threaded CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Using intents, you can adjust your app's user experience or ask other apps to perform common actions: taking photos, sending emails and SMS messages, and even displaying locations on maps and playing media. This course teaches you all you need to know to take advantage of this core piece of Android functionality.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).